# Laravel query builder - How to either group by alias, or do raw groupBy

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-5, query-builder

My Laravel 5 app includes a dynamic query builder for report running. I need some group by clauses in there and have run into a problem. If I use actual sql in there I can have issues as sometimes there needs to be a sql command in amongst the sql (as opposed to straightforward column names), ie - `DAYNAME(table_name.date_column)`. Laravel mangles this:

```
\`DAYNAME(table_name\`.\`date_column)\`
```

For the select part of my query I can use selectRaw, but there does not seem to be an equivaent for group by.

I thought of using aliases (all the selects are aliased) but Laravel wraps them in "`" characters as well. Besides - my app needs to work with both MySQL and SQL Server and as far as I know the latter does not allow aliases in the group by section of the query.

I can find the method in Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar where the group by is compiled (compileGroups) and I suppose I could override it but I'm not too sure how I would go about that (have read the Laravel docs).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to do raw groupBy, you can do something like this...

```
...->groupBy(DB::raw('some_alias'))
```

Comment: This answer helped me until I ran into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38262133/470749

Comment: That seems to be a different issue and doesn't add any context to this question.

Comment: I couldn't do `GROUP BY column DESC` ... this answer saved me, Thanks!

Comment: @Sodj You can do `ORDER By column DESC`