# In Laravel how to groupBy Url without parameter in the query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, url-parameters

The below query is with lots of join table and DB::raw query, Which is working as expected. I would like to groupBy a "landing" which is a field in the table has URL stored.
But I would like to groupBy URL without parameter. How can I achieve this?

Query below trying to use SUBSTRING_INDEX but didn't worked.

```
$adverts = DB::table('adverts')                     
              ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'),DB::raw('(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(instances.date), \'%d-%m-%Y\') FROM instances WHERE instances.ad_uid = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id DESC limit 1) AS Last_seen_date,'
                      . '(SELECT instances.country FROM instances WHERE instances.ad_uid = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id DESC limit 1) AS country,'
                      . '(SELECT advertsstorage.filename FROM advertsstorage where uid_dir = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id ASC limit 1) AS filename,'
                      .'(SELECT IF(ext = \'jpeg\', CONCAT(fullpath, \'_1.\', ext), (CONCAT(fullpath,\'.\',ext))) as fullpath FROM advertsstorage where uid_dir = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id ASC limit 1)as fullpath, adverts.*'))
               ->join('domains','adverts.domain', '=' ,'domains.domain') 
               ->join('advertiser_domains','domains.id', '=' ,'advertiser_domains.domain_id')
                 ->join('advertisers','advertiser_domains.advertiser_id', '=' ,'advertisers.u_id')   
              ->where('advertisers.u_id', '=',$advertiserID)
              ->orderBy('Last_seen_date', 'DESC')
              ->groupBy(DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(adverts.landing,'?',1)"))                    
             ->get();
```

Comment: +1. Did you ever figure out how to use Laravel groupBy with a parameter? I'm blocked by this same problem right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out, and now it makes sense to me that Laravel doesn't offer parameterization with `groupBy`.

First, I needed a refresher on [MySql Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Every field mentioned in your `select` needs to be compatible with what you put in your `groupBy`.

And you can use:
`->groupBy(DB::raw('some_alias'))`

In my case:

```
$statsQuery = DB::table('contacts')
                ->selectRaw("SUBSTR(DAYNAME(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC', ?)), 1, 3) AS 'DayOfWeek', HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC', ?)) AS 'Hour', COUNT(id) AS 'CallsScheduled'", [$reportingClientTimeZone, $reportingClientTimeZone])
                ->whereIn('adId', $adIds)
                ->whereRaw("CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC', ?) >= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d')", [$reportingClientTimeZone, $startDate]) //https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz
                ->whereRaw("CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC', ?) < DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 day)", [$reportingClientTimeZone, $endDate]) //Given a certain endDate (which begins at midnight), only include results LESS THAN 1 day after that midnight
                ->whereNotNull('clarityCallTimeUtc')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("DayOfWeek, Hour"));
```

See how `COUNT()` is my only aggregate function?  And the only other fields mentioned in my `select` are the ones I use (the aliases of) in the `groupBy`.

I think this is working for me.