# query raw inside groupBy in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a problem with my query when I'm trying to group by Date(timestamp) in my laravel project, lets see my code.

> RekapController@index

```
public function index()
{
    $absen = Absen::groupBy(raw('DATE(created_at)'))
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->get();
    return view('rekap.index')->with('data', $absen);
}
```

in my sql syntax is work perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM absen GROUP BY DATE(created_at) DESC
```

how can I fix this?

Edit:

The Error is

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\raw()

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370577/laravel-query-builder-how-to-either-group-by-alias-or-do-raw-groupby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel query builder - How to either group by alias, or do raw groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370577/laravel-query-builder-how-to-either-group-by-alias-or-do-raw-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
           $absen = Absen::groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: @Azzario Razy please try this.

Comment: @Azzario Razy Glad i could help